# \lstdefinestyle lists, not arabic numbers but rather roman?

Tags: lists, roman-numerals, lstdefinestyle

I'm sorry to bother. 
I have a \lstdefinestyle define in which I define the colours and size of the fonts, etc, to be shown in a code that I'm placing in a tex document. However, all my document is written in roman numbers (chapters, equations, etc), I wonder if there is a way to change the line-code-numbers into romans...
Thank you for your help but I have been wondering around long time and I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the `listings` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (page 35) you can redefine `\thelstnumber` to change the line numbers. Roman numbers for a counter can be printed with `\roman{name of the counter}`, so in this case `\roman{lstnumber}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\roman{lstnumber}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
sixth line
seventh line
eighth line
ninth line
tenth line
eleventh line
twelfth line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now I can I know how to do it.